# How to make the width of the search results same as the HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make the width of the search results same as the HTML table?
Please see the code here -
https://codepen.io/magic12/pen/ZExKNjY

Problem: When I search the term "test12" versus the term "xyz", the result width differs. I would like to keep the results width consistent all the time. It should be the same size as the table.

```js
    function myFunction() {
      const userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
      const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
      for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
        const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
        tableRows[i].style.display = rowTextContent.toUpperCase().includes(userInput) ? "" : "none";
      }
    }
```

```css
    table.table_brdr td {
        padding: 8px 10px;
        border: none;
    }
    
    table.table_brdr th {
        background-color: #a6a6a6;
        color: black;
    }
    
    tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
          background-color#D3D3D3;
    }
    
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 20%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
```

```html
    <p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search" title="Searche"></p>
    <table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th><strong>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>xyz</td>
    <td>03/30/2017</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>test12</td>
    <td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
    <td>03/30/2017</td>
    </tr>
      
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th> New Column</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>abctd <td>
    <td>09/30/2019</td>
    </tr>
      
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th> New Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>abctd </td>
    <td>06/30/2019</td>
    </tr>
    
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Your HTML has an unmatched open `<strong>` tag and an unmatched closing `</tbody>` tag.

Comment: Add `td { width: 100px;}` to your css

Comment: you also have `<td>abctd <td>`  and `<td>abctd <td>` tags errors...

Comment: Basically, while the browser will often be quite forgiving with malformed HTML, it can yield confusing, difficult to debug results.  You should be leveraging tooling in your editor to make sure that your HTML is properly formed and conforming to the spec before attempting to debug any other issues.

Comment: why your table use an ending tag `</tbody>` without previous `<tbody>`  ?

Comment: Why do you use `<th><strong>Column2</th>` without `</strong>` ending tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add width to your `<td>` in your css.
try this code:

```
td { width: 100px;}
```

Comment: I am not able to. I am getting this message: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.